# SharePoint 2013 workflow check if user has already enter a record

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

i need some help with workflows...

how do check if a user has already created an entry in a custom list.
dont allow the user to enter another entry, send an email if the user has.
if the user hasnt created an entry allow the user to do it.
custom list has the following columns:

Title : Meeting : meetingID : Username : created by:

here is the sample for my workflow so far...

[image]

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this using a secondary list to hold all users that have created items. This might not work for your purposes, but here's how I did it:

Create a second list (let's call it Creators). You won't need any custom columns, as you will only be using the "Title" column in this list.

Consider your primary list (let's call it Class Attendees).

**Firstly**, do not forget to set the following workflow to run when an item is created!!

When an item is created in Class Attendees, I set a workflow variable (I called it Current User) to the following value:

**Field Data to Retrive**

Data source: Creators

Field from source: Title (column)

Return field as: As String

**Find the List Item**

Field: Title

Value: Current Item: Created By (As String)

**NOTE**: *You will get a warning about multiple values being returned. It's okay for this workflow though.*

[image: Details for Creators:Title]

Then, I created a Condition:

**If**

Current Item: Created By **equals** Variable: Current User

**Email** Current Item: Created By (craft the email as you see fit)

**then** 
Delete Item in Current Item (this will remove the second item, but not their first).

**Else** (very important to keep track of your item creators)

**Create item** in Creators (set Title to Current Item: Created By: **As String** (very important for matching).
[image: Workflow Overview]
[image: Details for Create Item in Creators]

When you test it, make sure Creators is empty at first. Then, create a single item in Class Attendees. You should receive no email, and your SP username will show in the Creators List. Now, try to create a second item in Class Attendees. If set up properly, the WF will catch this, delete your second item, and send you an email about it.

Please let me know if this works for you!

Best,

Chris Dennett

Comment: Chris,
thank you for your quick response, I will give this a try and let you know

Comment: I edited this to make it more readable. Also will be adding a few screenshots of the workflow overview and variable details to hopefully help a little. :)

Comment: thanks again for your help, on the Details for Creator:Title or the Look up for single line of text i get the options of (see attached) but not the "As String" option.
not sure how i can insert a screenshot to comments...
so, on the return field for the lookup for single line of text i get                                          

DATASOURCE:             Current Item
FIELD FROM SOURCE:  Created by
RETURN FIELD:             (Display Name, Email Address, Login Name, User Id Number) those are the choices i get on the dropdown box..."As String" is not one of them...

Comment: Hmmm, that is odd. There is one point where the WF didn't give me the option to choose, but I'm pretty certain that the option was As String anyway, so I didn't worry about it. Is this happening during the assignment of the variable (the one I called CurrentUser), or during the item creation in the secondary list (the one I called Creators)?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have no idea why the comments are limited to be able to have a conversation...so,

This isn't working, I don't know if it is my workflow, or it just doesn't work because of sharepoint...

I created two lists...
 - Class Seats, and Class Attendees,
 - class seats has the classes I need to create for users to register...
 - Class Attendees has the names of the users registered for class...
 - Class Attendees has the following columns:
 - Title, Meeting, MeetingID, Username

I created a workflow which registers the user for class so
I need a workflow which checks if the user has already registered for class and doesn't allow the user to do so if already registered.

I have tried the following workflow...

- Set VariableID to Class Attendees:Title
- Data Source: class Attendees
- Field from Source : Title (return as String)
- Find the list Item:
- Field: Username Value: Current List: Created by  (when you click on
- the (fx) button ) Data Source: Current List
- Field from Source:
- Created by Return Field: Display Name (other choices are, Email, Log
  in, userID Number)
- Find the List Item: Field:
- Username value: Current Item: Username (as a string)
- if Current Item:Username uquals Variable:UsenameID
- email,
- then delete item in current item
- transition to stage registered for class Update item in Class Seats
  (which creates a user)

it creates a user but the check part wont work...so please help figure this out...thank you All
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, using your List and Column names, your workflow should be set up like this:

1. Set UsernameID to the value of the column you are using in Class Attendees (I used the Title column), to hold the username of the person creating the item in Class Seats. In order to match properly, what you write to the Username column in Class Attendees will need to match what you are checking for. In your screenshot, you seem to be setting your UsernameID variable to Class Attendees:MeetingID. This might cause the non-match. When this step is finished for me, UsernameID = i:0#.w|{domain}\chrisbd, as long as I've already created one item in Class Seats. That's just SharePoint's version of a user's username as a string. So the key here is that if this is the user's first item, we want to allow the item to be created, but also create a new item in Class Attendees to show that they've created one. You will need to write the value of Class Seats:Created By to a column of Class Attendees as a string.
2. The important part about this first check is that we know that there is one column in Class Attendees that contains usernames. We want the workflow to look at all values in that column, and return any value that matches the String value of the current user. When setting your variable, you need to set the data source as Class Attendees, using the column where you store the username (as a string).
3. In my example, I use the Title column of Class Attendees to store the username value as a string, but I don't do this until after the check has passed (which is in my "Else" clause of the condition check).
4. Example: I am creating my first item in Class Seats. When I click "Save", the workflow searches the Class Attendees:Title column for a match on my Username as a string. My Field Data To Retrieve is set up as mentioned above:

**Field Data to Retrive**

Data source: Class Attendees

Field from source: Title (column)

Return field as: As String

**Find the List Item**

Field: Title

Value: Current Item: Created By (As String)

***NOTE: You will get a warning about multiple values being returned. It's okay for this workflow though.***

5. This tells SharePoint to search the Title column of Class Attendees, and return the item where Title matches the String value of the user who created the current Class Seats item. If you aren't comparing String to String, or if you are writing a value other than String to Class Attendees, the matching will not work. For this example, the workflow will not find a match (because this is my first item).
6. Next comes the "If" statement. In this example, it will return FALSE, because this is my first item. But, the key here is that we are checking the variable (which, if set, will be the String of a username), against the String of the username of the person currently attempting to create the item in Class Seats.
7. Since this is my first item, the "If" check fails, and the workflow must now create a new item in Class Attendees, so that if I try to make a second item in Class Seats, the "If" check will succeed next time. When creating the Class Attendees item, it is very important that there is a column to store the user's String username. You can, of course, set as many additional columns however you like, but since we are using Title for matching (in my example), then you need to write the current user's String username into the Title column of Class Attendees (since this is the column we search when setting our variable in Step 1 above).

Now, I'm going to try and create a second item in Class Seats. When I click "Save", the workflow will again search the Title column of Class Attendees. We want to retrieve the item in Class Attendees where the Title column matches the String username of me. Since we just wrote a new item to Class Attendees when I created my first item, there will be an item with my String username in the Title field of Class Attendees. Since the workflow found this match, we store that value in the variable.

Next, the "If" statement compares the variable (my String username) to my String username, obviously finding them to be equal. Since the "If" succeeds this time, we want to email me, and delete the item I just saved.

Bottom line, I suggest looking at how you are creating the item in Class Attendees, and make absolutely sure that you are writing the String of the username into a column there. When setting your variable, make sure you are using that same column to find a match to the current user's String username. If a match is found, email and delete. If not, create the item in Class Attendees with at least one column storing the current user's String username.

If you need more help, let me know and I will find a way to message you privately.

Best,

Chris Dennett

Comment: Thanks for taking the time YET AGAIN Chris, i really appreciate it...i will try this solution and let you know..